# IntelliSense does not work in windows/analytical functions

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to get IntelliSense to work inside windows/analytical functions? For example:

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY BusinessEntityID ORDER BY BusinessEntityID)
```

I have to enter the BusinessEntityID name fully, no IntelliSense's suggestions pop up (even when the parenthesis are closed).

Comment: Use something other than the native intellisense. There are lots of plugins that are light years better than the built in intellisense.

Comment: And if it is a problem, you should be raising it as a bug [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server). I can, however, confirm that this isn't an issue with Redgate SQL Prompt (just one example of the plugins Sean mentions).

Comment: @Sean Lange So it does not work in SSMS by definition? I find it peculiar, since those are widely used functions. What is even more peculiar - i have not find any question on this matter asked here.

Comment: Try it in Azure Studio. It's free and allows for a higher memory allocation. It has the advantage of a lot more plugins than SSMS to increase productivity.

Comment: It is actually more wide spread than just window functions. Nearly any function the intellisense doesn't work inside the parenthesis.

Comment: @Sean Lange I beg to differ - every SQL Server function using parenthesised arguments (at least the most common - aggregates, conversion, date and time, etc.) are working fine with IntelliSense, except for analytical functions. This is exactly why I am perplexed.

Comment: @MichaelShuv maybe they have improved it over the last 2-3 versions so that it does work more consistently. It used to be so bad that it barely worked at all.